# how to prompt search query into a dynamic iframe

Tags: php, search, iframe, mysqli

hi there i am creating a data grid which loads data from the database and i had even created a search box which prompts the search queries when a user inputs a value into it but now i want to show my search query into the same iframe which is loading the file of data table and when the search box is empty  it should show the data table and if a user enters a query it should load the query into it here is my script

```
                                     <div style="float: right; border: 1px; padding-right: 20px;">
                                          <div class="search">
                                               <input type="text" name="s" maxlength="64"  placeholder="Search" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);"  />
                                               <img src="images/srch.png"  id="srch_btn"/> 
                                          </div>
                                         </div>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                                <table border="0" width="100%" class="myclass"  height="30px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="80px"  align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Sr No.</font></td>
                                        <td width="80px"  align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Br No.</font></td>
                                        <td width="180px" align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Name</font></td>
                                        <td width="200px" align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Address</font></td>
                                        <td width="120px" align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">City</font></td>
                                        <td width="80px"  align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Pin</font></td>
                                        <td width="80px"  align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Mobile</font></td>
                                        <td width="120px"  align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Email</font></td>
                                        <td width="80px" class="myclass" align="center"><font color="black" size="3px">Actions</font></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                 <div id="suggestions">/****file that shows the search queries**/
                                     <iframe src="record.php" width="1150" height="900" frameBorder="0"></iframe> /** File that loads the data table**/
                                 </div>
```

here is my search script

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mdb');

    if(!$db) {
        // Show error if we cannot connect.
        echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
    } else {
        // Is there a posted query string?
        if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
            $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

            if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
                $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mdb  WHERE (`name` LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%') OR (grno LIKE '%". $queryString ."%')
                                                    OR (`address` LIKE '%". $queryString ."%') OR (`city` LIKE '%". $queryString ."%') OR (pin LIKE '%". $queryString ."%')
                                                    OR (mobile LIKE '%". $queryString ."%') OR (`email` LIKE'%". $queryString ."%')  ORDER BY vouchno LIMIT 8");

                if($query) {
                    echo "<table width='100%'>";
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th align=left>Name</th>";
                                        echo "<th align=left>Address</th>";
                                        echo "<th align=left>City</th>";
                                        echo "<th align=left>Pin</th>";
                                        echo "<th align=right>Mobile</th>";
                                        echo "<th align=left>Email</th>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td><span class=\"category\">$result->name</span></td>";
                                        echo "<td>$result->address</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$result->city</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$result->pin</td>";
                                        echo "<td align=right>$result->mobile</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$result->email</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td colspan=9>";
                                        echo "<hr/>";
                                        echo "</td>";
                                        echo "<tr>";

                                        $name = $result->name;
                        if(strlen($name) > 35) { 
                            $name = substr($name, 0, 35) . "...";
                        }                       

                        $description = $result->address;
                        if(strlen($description) > 80) { 
                            $description = substr($description, 0, 80) . "...";
                        }


                    }
                                echo "</table>";
                    echo '<span class="seperator"><strong>No Further Records Found</strong> </span><br class="break" />';
                } else {
                    echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
                }
            } else {
                            echo "record.php";
            } 
        } else {
            echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why iframe is needed here?

Comment: because i need that i frame to show my other php file which fetches the records from the database and i am using infinite scroll plugin to show my records into it

Comment: yea that would be really great of u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now AJAX can help you I mean. why you don't do somthing like this instead of iframe?
 check [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#div').load('someFile.php','params');
```

and for scrolling the div use this in CSS

CSS

```
#div{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

here the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YqW5Q/).